# How to use the proper video driver on Scientific Linux 6 for Display Port screens?

Tags: kernel, drivers, scientific-linux, gpu, displayport

I am working with (one of) my workstation(s) working under Scientific Linux 6, so, basically a quite old version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I would need to use 2 screens, but only have 2 DisplayPort  and one VGA as outputs from my Intel IGP. I am unable to make the DisplayPort ports working, I guess because the driver and kernel used are too old.

Anyone would have an idea (besides using a dedicated GPU) ?

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a102 (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)

uname -a
Linux pcbe13615 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 17:13:03 CET 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: `xorg.conf` is empty. The Xorg log is too big. Could you tell me what you are looking for so I can copy/paste what you are interested in.

Comment: You could use something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to upload the log file, but you could also post here at least the lines with `(WW)` or `(EE)` (for warnings and errors). But I'd suspect this is due to your very old kernel not supporting the new GPU of the Skylake processor. Please post also the output of `lspci -n |grep 00:02.0` since the the actual device code is not shown in the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the lack of support for the GPU in kernel (and likely also in X.Org video driver) which you need to somehow solve. Proper support for Sky Lake based GPUs in `i915` kernel driver should be available [from kernel 4.4 on](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Skylake_Support). Then again, myself I still couldn't get a Intel GPU with device code 1912 working in Debian Jessie under 4.4.5 due to something with possibly the X.org version in Jessie (haven't tried any later kernel now, though). So it'll be either major upgrade of the system, or a dedicated GPU.

Getting a used common good known brand GPU which your system has support for could be the easiest way out, but I'm not sure if you could find one that has specifically DisplayPort available.

If you don't want to upgrade the system, you could try just taking a recent kernel and compiling that manually with all the required options to support the GPU. The possible problem with this approach is that it might be hard to get the system to boot with the new kernel, as there might be some conflicts between the kernel and the base software of the system, `udev` being one possible issue. You'd also need to remember to include much of the deprecated stuff to be compatible with the older software which interfaces the kernel.

Intel does even provide [sources for their graphics driver](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/development/source-code), so if you are willing to try every possible thing, you could try also compiling that.

In addition to compiling either the Linux kernel or just the Intel graphics driver, you'd still also need to get recent enough X.Org Intel video driver which also supports Skylake based GPUs, so you'd probably also end up needing to compile that (possibly the whole of X.Org), too. This might prove to be impossible without upgrading large parts of the rest of the system due to conflicting version requirements for many other components. After all, there is a reason why most people rely on prebuilt distributions instead of trying to get things going from the scratch :)

Comment: For me, no, it's not about the GPU but getting rid of the VESA driver (too old for this kind of port and not "supported" anymore). The question is : with this kernel version, is it possible to get something like Nouveau to work ?

Comment: That's also why I said I would prefer another option than just "switch to a dedicated card" because this won't solve the driver issue (and the compatibility with the kernel).

Comment: Old kernels don't have drivers for new hardware. That is why I suggested getting older (used) hardware. As for Nouveau, that is for nVidia GPUs. I don't know if there is similar project for Intel GPUs, but even Nouveau relies on the kernel to do things. You can rid of the vesa driver by explicitly asking X.org to use intel driver (see e.g. [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206172) for pointers), but I bet you just end up with the driver saying that it doesn't know of your hardware.

Comment: I added some more possible solutions in case you are feeling adventurous, but they are tough ones to get right, and still might prove impossible without upgrading the rest of the system (which I assumed is something that you either don't want to or can't do).